# Position Views side by side in main view in WPF with MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, datatemplate

I have a WPF desktop app built with MVVM and have all the views available in MainWindow.xaml. The problem is that the views are listed in the order they appear in Window.Resources, each stretching accross the screen. I want 2 of the views to appear in the main window side by side.

To clarify, there is a tabcontrol view that contains a tree visualisation and beside that are 2 expanders that open and display info from inside the tabs. Because the app lists out the views the expanders are under the tab area. I want them to lie beside and pop up over (partially obscuring) the tab.

This gets the observableCollection ViewModels (MainWindow.xaml):

```
<ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}"
```

and they are added in the  MainWindow ViewModel class thusly:

```
SearchExpanderViewModel viewModel6 = new SearchExpanderViewModel(decisiontreeRepository);
    this.ViewModels.Add(viewModel6);
```

How do I put 2 views side by side in the MainWindow view when I can't put them in a grid?

Thanks in advance!

**edit:** screenshot
I can't add images or anything because of reputation, link here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSJ2S.jpg

Comment: Please change the title; you are not positioning ViewModels

Answer (score 0):

It was to add the "coordinates" to these lines in the mainWindowViewModel:

```
ExpandersViewModel expanderStackpanelViewModel = new ExpandersViewModel(2,1,1,1,
decisiontreeRepository);
this.ViewModels.Add(expanderStackpanelViewModel);
```

and use a  grid in the xaml file, and add getters and setters for rows and columns to the viewmodel for the specific view:

```
 public class PathExpanderViewModel : ViewModelBase{  
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Col { get; set; }

    public PathExpanderViewModel(int row, int col){
         Row = row;
         Col = col;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else with the same problem, although it's still not 100% clear to me :)